# Две версии Python

Tags: python, cmd, cocos2d

Как переключаться между версиями пайтона в командной строке .
мне нужен пайтон 2.7 для cocos2d  но также мне нужен пайтон 3.9 .
как мне работать с этими двумя версиями , если в командной строке есть только 3.9 версия .
3.9 нужна для pycharm и для себя , и ета версия не поддерживает кокос2д , так что 2.7 версия нужна только для кокоса

Answer (score 2):

При запуске укажите путь к интерпретатору
Например для запуска 3.9 можно так:

```
C:\Python\Python39\python.exe myscript.py
```

А для 2.7 можно соответственно:

```
C:\Python\Python27\python.exe myscript.py
```

Еще можно указать интерпретатор первой строкой в скрипте:

```py
#! C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

Тогда можно запускать хоть двойным кликом подцепится тот что указан. Поддерживает ли это 2.7 не факт.